# Multiple relations between models

Tags: javascript, database, relationship, prisma, prisma2

I am struggling to understand how to build multiple relations between two models. Take the following:

```
model User {
  id             Int       @default(autoincrement()) @id
  goalBoard      GoalBoard[]
  ...
}

model GoalBoard {
  id          Int         @default(autoincrement()) @id
  goalOwner   User        @relation(fields: [goalOwnerId], references: [id])
  goalOwnerId Int
  invitee     User[]      @relation(name: "invitee") //?
  invited     User[]      @relation(name: "invited") //?
  ...
  @@unique([goalOwnerId, active])
}
```

The 'invitee' & 'invited' fields will have multiple users within them. I am not clear on the need / requirement for the adding a `name` to the `@relation`.

So, for understanding sake, what is the purpose behind naming the `@relation`. And secondly, how would I build the relation as per my requirement above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the right and clear way to do your multiple many to many relations

[image]

```
model User {
  id               Int         @default(autoincrement()) @id
  goalBoardInvitee GoalBoard[] @relation(name: "UserGoalBoardInvitee")
  goalBoardInvited GoalBoard[] @relation(name: "UserGoalBoardInvited")
  ...
}

model GoalBoard {
  id          Int         @default(autoincrement()) @id
  goalOwner   User        @relation(fields: [goalOwnerId], references: [id])
  goalOwnerId Int
  invitee     User[]      @relation(name: "UserGoalBoardInvitee") //?
  invited     User[]      @relation(name: "UserGoalBoardInvited") //?
  ...
  @@unique([goalOwnerId, active])
}
```

To understand why we do this, please read the [Prisma relations docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-schema/relations#many-to-many-relations)

Comment: Thank you so much and as always Ahmed. Finally, this makes sense to me. Cheers.

Comment: Any reason makes you not mark my Answer the correct answer?

Comment: I wanted to implement it to make sure I didnt have any further questions. Am going to implement and test the logic now. So hope to mark it soon. Thank you again for the help!